# Django form using DateTimeRangeField will not validate

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

When trying to check if the form is valid using `.is_valid()`, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'` for my DateTimeRangeField. I am using `RangeWidget(forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(date_attrs={"type": "date"}, time_attrs={"type": "time"},),),` with postgres db.

I switched the backend from sqlite3 to postgres so I could use the DateTimeRangeField and the debugger shows the correct information in the POST request.  Do I need to switch my `datetimerange` column/field into two columns, `datetime_start` and `datetime_stop`? Or is there another way to validate that I have missed?

Should I just separate out the range into a separate form and use a key to connect it to my current form? I would like to add the ability to add many time ranges in the same form in the future.